# Show page in modal popup if dekstop version (lg, md) is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display my login/register page content in bootstrap modal form if site is displayed in "desktop" version (e.g. lg, md) and in a new window if it's a mobile version (e.g. xs). How can this be done?

Comment: You can try an if statement

Comment: You could have 2 divs, show div 1 when in fullscreen, then use jQuery to make it a modal pop up. Then in mobile, hide div 1, and use div 2 which is a link with `'target:_blank'` to allow it to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two buttons. One with the modal setup on it and one with a link to the standalone login page. My solution involves using the built in [bootstraps responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), which are just classes in which you can use in your markup.

---

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default visible-xs-block" href="//domain.com/login">Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-default hidden-xs" modal-stuff >Login</a>
```

The classes `hidden-*` and `visible-*-*` pretty much do what they say on the tin, show and hide content depending on the BS classes for media screen size. Although, with the `visible-*-*` class, remember to change the `block`, `inline` or `inline-block` depending on what you require BS to make the display type when it is made visible.

Hope that helped!